# onChange is not working but is logged in the console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For the `input` case I cannot delete and/or add any character. I see the values for the radio buttons being changed in `console.log` but not visually. I'm not sure why it's behaving this way.

```
handleChange: function(e) {
        switch (e.target.name) {
        case 'name':
            this.setState({newName: e.target.value}); break;
        case 'type':
            this.setState({newType: e.target.value}); break;
}

nameFormatter: function(id, name) {
        return (this.state.editEnabled && this.state.editId === id) ?
            <input type="text"
                value={name}
                name="name"
                maxLength="50"
                onChange={this.handleChange} /> : name;
    },

    typeFormatter: function(id, type) {
        type = type === 'blacklist' ? 'Blacklist' : 'Whitelist';
        return (this.state.editEnabled && this.state.editId === id) ?
            <div>
                <div><input type="radio"
                    name="ipsetType"
                    value="blacklist"
                    checked={type === 'Blacklist'}
                    onChange={this.handleChange} />&nbsp;Blacklist</div>
                <div><input
                    type="radio"
                    name="type"
                    value="whitelist"
                    checked={type === 'Whitelist'}
                    onChange={this.handleChange} />&nbsp;Whitelist</div>
            </div> : type;
    },
```

Comment: need to set value to the value of the state https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Comment: Don't use statement for value in input. It makes your inputs uncontrolled. Cause you can't type any character into input...  Check the documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because your `handleChange` sets state for `newName` and `newType` whereas you need to do it for `name and type`

```
handleChange: function(e) {
        switch (e.target.name) {
        case 'name':
            this.setState({name: e.target.value}); break;
        case 'type':
            this.setState({type: e.target.value}); break;
}
```

Comment: Also, dhouldn't `ipsetType` be `name`?

Answer (score 0):

Try onchange instead of onChange.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are changing the wrong values, also make sure the checked property is comparing against the right value. Try this:

```
handleChange: function(e) {
        var values;

        switch (e.target.name) {
          case 'name':
            values = {name: e.target.value}; break;
          case 'type':
            values = {type: e.target.value}; break;
       }

       // Try to always have a single call to setState in your methods
       this.setState(values);
}

nameFormatter: function(id, name) {
        return (this.state.editEnabled && this.state.editId === id) ?
            <input type="text"
                value={name}
                name="name"
                maxLength="50"
                onChange={this.handleChange} /> : name;
},

typeFormatter: function(id, type) {
    // don't mutate the params
    //type = type === 'blacklist' ? 'Blacklist' : 'Whitelist';
    // instead create a new variable
    var label = type === 'blacklist' ? 'Blacklist' : 'Whitelist';
    return (this.state.editEnabled && this.state.editId === id) ?
        <div>
            <div><input type="radio"
                name="ipsetType"
                value="blacklist"
                checked={type === 'blacklist'}
                onChange={this.handleChange} />&nbsp;Blacklist</div>
            <div><input
                type="radio"
                name="type"
                value="whitelist"
                checked={type === 'whitelist'}
                onChange={this.handleChange} />&nbsp;Whitelist</div>
        </div> : label ;
},
```